# API for registering a free domain

Tags: api, dns, tld

I'm working on a project the requires me to register a domain for a user based on input. I want an API that I can call that will let me register a free domain for the user. The TLD does not matter, i'm open to things like .co.cc, .co.nr, etc. I already saw the .TK affiliate program, but it seemed a little shady. Again, both the API and the domain have to be free.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of any free domain registries.  You probably want to look into creating a DNS sub-domain, where if you have the domain "myapp.com", a user can create the subdomain "user1.myapp.com".  Those would be free, depending on how you're hosted and who runs your DNS.